# Butane smell normal?

Tags: gas, smell

I bought some of this [Vector 14x Butane](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FP2XT92)

To use in a [Butane Soldering Iron](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DIE9BO) and every time I turn on the Iron, there's a really strong rotten egg/gas smell (and it lingers even after 30 secs).  Is this normal?

I had a small torch years back and got some cheap butane from 7-11 and it never smelled so strong (could barely smell it) before when I turned it on.  Not even my gas stove smells that bad after using it for an hour.

Is it the butane? I bought the Vector cause the Iron said to use premium butane.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's relatively normal for some gas to escape before it starts burning.

The smell is from an additive called Ethanethiol (ethyl mercaptan) which has a strong odor that humans can detect in very small concentrations.  You only smell it from escaped gas and not a byproduct of combustion, hence why you won't smell it relative to the duration of the burn.

Comment: Can I assume that the cheap butane I bought did not have (or barely had any) Ethanethiol in it? Actually thinking about it, even with a propane BBQ, I could smell the gas but it was fairly normal gas smell which was tolerable.  This stuff is quite pungent.

Comment: I don't think there is any standard for how much to put in, so it might just be a matter of concentration.  Also your BBQ is outside and there is usually a breeze so it will disperse a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

Actually that smell is a new thing. I've been buying Vector Butane for years off Amazon, and only last year did I get my first case with that overdose of Godawful additive.

I believe they did that to thwart idiots seeking a cheap high inhaling the gas.